# PuTTY fatal error - Disconnected: Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for not existent channel 258

Tags: svn, putty

I need to connect to the our server, that download the project using PuTTY. When i trying to do 'Checkout' using TortoiseSVN, several files was loaded and i get error messages:

1). from svn - Error: REPORT of '/blabla/blabla/blabla/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response. Body: Secure connection truncated (https://localhost).
2). from putty - PuTTY fatal error: Disconnected: Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for not existent channel 258.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a bug on server side. if you use freesshd on windows, you can try to switch to Openssh server